# How to change cursor style when hover over elements that had cursor pointer

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse

I disables the mouse of the page by cursor none of the whole body of the document, and adds my custom svg and use translate x and y with the mouse move event to set the custom mouse position. But on some places like a button, text, the cursor is shown to be pointer and text default, is there any way to detect whether the cursor had changed to pointer or any other and change it to my own custom pointer design like svg?

I tried mouseover event in javascript, but when I hover over a button with pointer, it works, but not sure how to disable it and add my own custom svg there?

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
  var cursor = getComputedStyle(e.target).cursor;
  console.log(cursor);
  if(cursor == 'pointer') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('no-cursor')
  }
});
```

```css
.no-cursor {cursor: none !important}
```

Please attach a small example, it would be a great help :)

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  document.querySelector('.mover').style.transform = `translate(${event.pageX}px, ${event.pageY}px)`
  
});
```

```css
.mover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -8px;
  top: -6px;
}

html {
  cursor: none;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #F5F9FF;
  
}

.btn {
    --background: #5628EE;
    --shadow: rgba(84, 40, 238, .16);
    --y: 0;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background: var(--background);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 23px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px var(--shadow);
    transform: translateY(var(--y));
    transition: box-shadow .3s ease, transform .3s ease;
    &:hover {
        --y: -2px;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px var(--shadow);
    }
    &:active {
        --y: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px var(--shadow);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="mover">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12 ,2Z"></path>
</svg>
</div>

<a href="" class="btn">Call to action</a>
```

please don't suggest manual ways of doing this, I want to do this all automatically

Comment: If want to display your custom cursor when hovering the `<a>` element you'll need a higher `z-index` value (e.g. 100) - otherwise its rendered under the button.

Comment: @herrstrietzel, Thank you for answering, but that was not what I want to do, because I have some transition of the custom cursor, so still would look like a pointer is appearing, I want to remove the pointer mouse and change it to my custom inner html svg and move that when hovering over an element that had the mouse pointer

Comment: @herrstrietzel, I tried your approach, but it seems that even if I set a hight z-index for my custom mouse, it would not appear on top of the default mouse

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do without scripts and set the desired cursor appearance for different elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #F5F9FF;
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath d='M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12 ,2Z' fill='black'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") 12 22, pointer;
}

.btn {
  --background: #5628EE;
  --shadow: rgba(84, 40, 238, .16);
  --y: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: translateY(var(--y));
  font: 500 16px/23px Roboto, Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px var(--shadow);
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease, transform .3s ease;
  cursor: inherit;
}
.btn:hover { --y: -2px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px var(--shadow); }
.btn:active { --y: 1px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px var(--shadow); }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Call to action</a>
```

Comment: Yep, but that's not what I am looking for, I am using transform property, so I can't specify the default mouse

Comment: @JoelSmith: What exactly are you using the transform property for?

Comment: I am using to change the x and y position of the element, so that it may appear that its a cursor, and I am using it because I want to change transition and animation property on that cursor